# Wrapper height overflowing into footer

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I want to have a sticky footer but I also want my main div to end right before the footer for the height but the wrapper is not moving up like it normally would if you have negative margin and I don't know why. Even with a min-height I should be able to move it up. When I increase the negative margin nothing happens. Basically I just need my wrapper to be the 100 percent height minus the height of the footer.  The div of interest is the one with the blue background. Now my sidebar is perfectly fine(or at least it should be), as it ends right before the black footer.

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #99ff33;
}


#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 85%;
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh-130px);
    margin-bottom: -130px;
}

#wrapper:after{
    content: "";
    display:block;
}

#footer, #wrapper:after{
    height: 130px;
}


.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.sub {
    padding: 12px;
    width: 32%;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    border-right: solid white 1px;
}

.sub:last-child{
    border: 0px;
}

#sidebar{
    float:left;
    background-color: yellow;
    height:calc(100vh - 130px);
    width: 7.5%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#footer {
    display: flex;
    height: 130px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<div id="footer">
   <div class="wrap">
      <div class="sub"></div>
      <div class="sub"></div>
      <div class="sub"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up your directions, silly goose!

```
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 85%;
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh-130px);
    margin-top: -130px;

}
```

**`margin-top`** vs **`margin-bottom`**

Comment: Oh thanks. Ok I made my sidebar 100% height instead to account for that margin-top, BUT if you take a look at this picture you'll notice that there is a sliver of the body background color between the wrapper and the footer. How much more should I add to cover that up? Why is that coming in?

https://snag.gy/C8RrtN.jpg

Comment: Ah I found it. It was the pseudo after div. Well I'll be darned, you can do the bottom footer without one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `min-height: 100%;` this will make it always make it 100% height of it's parent. Add a space to you math in the `calc` function and add a `border` to make it the same size as your toolbar. I also removed the `relative` position.

Here's the new css for `#wrapper`:

```
#wrapper{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 85%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: calc(100vh - 130px);
}
```

And the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdm5ng6o/).

**UPDATE:**

Here's a quote from MDN about surrounding the operand of calc with whitespace:

> Note: The + and - operators must always be surrounded by whitespace. The operand of calc(50% -8px) for instance will be parsed as a percentage followed by a negative length, an invalid expression, while the operand of calc(50% - 8px) is a percentage followed by a minus sign and a length. Even further, calc(8px + -50%) is treated as a length followed by a plus sign and a negative percentage.
>   The * and / operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is allowed, and recommended.

You can find out more about calc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Also, `calc` is not highly supported and is subject to change. So I would not recommend using it or at least have a fallback.

Comment: That's really weird. My whole sidebar disappears when I do it, and all you really see is the green background. Also what's the blue outlining around the sidebar? Here's my new fiddle, but it should be the same as yours:

https://jsfiddle.net/pr96g63f/

Comment: The blue outline around the sidebar is from your original code. You have the style `border: 1px solid blue;` for `#sidebar`. This creates the blue 'outlining' around the sidebar.

Comment: Also you need to add a space whenever you do `height:calc(100vh - 130px);` so if you change this in your fiddle when styling `#sidebar` it should look the same as mine.